# Example where Ermakoff's convergence test is inconclusive

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Ermakoff's test states that for a nonincreasing function $f(x)$, $\sum f(n)$ converges if

$$\limsup_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^x f(e^x)}{f(x)} < 1$$

and diverges if

$$\liminf_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^x f(e^x)}{f(x)} > 1.$$

This test seems to be very powerful in that any example I try gives a limit of $0$ or $\infty$.

**Question:** Is there an example where Ermakoff's test is inconclusive, i.e. is there an $f(x)$ that gives a limit of 1? More generally, is there an $f(x)$ that gives a finite positive limit?

---

My approach was to toe the line between slowly diverging summands like $\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n \log n}, \frac{1}{n \log n \log\log n}, \ldots$ I tried throwing in special functions that grow differently than a power of a nested logarithm, such as [$li(x)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogarithmicIntegral.html) and [$W(x)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html). This didn't get me very far as I ended up wandering aimlessly through examples.

By taking the logarithm of the limit and performing substitutions, it's equivalent to look for a nondecreasing function $g(x)$ where $\lim_{x \to \infty} (x - g(x) + g(\log x)) = 0$. This form makes working with series at $x = \infty$ a bit easier.

---

The test can be generalized by looking at $\phi'(x) f(\phi(x))/f(x)$ for any increasing $\phi(x) > x$. Letting $\phi(x) = e^x$ gives Ermakoff's test and letting $\phi(x) = x + 1$ gives d'Alembert's ratio test.

**Bonus question:** Is there a way to find an inconclusive example for any $\phi(x)$? I imagine the faster $\phi(x)$ grows, the harder it becomes.

Comment: My script, nfnitseriestst.m (written in MATLAB and on the File Exchange) shows through testing that Ermakoff's test is indeed good at logarithm's, and is a powerful convergence test. I have not found a series where the limit is equal to 1. The limit is always zero or Inf, or doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

We can find a counterexample by treating the limit in question as a functional equation (a stronger condition), i.e. solve the functional equation

$$ f(e^x) = f(x)e^{-x} \implies f(x) = f(\log x)/x. $$

Choosing the initial values $f(x) = 1$ for $0 \leq x < 1$ yields a *continuous* solution through forward propogation:

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      1 & 0 \leq x < 1 \\
      \frac{1}{x} & 1 \leq x < e \\
      \frac{1}{x \log x} & e \leq x < e^e \\
      \frac{1}{x \log x \log \log x} & e^e \leq x < e^{e^e} \\
      \frac{1}{x \log x \log \log x \log\log\log x} & e^{e^e} \leq x < e^{e^{e^e}} \\
      \vdots & \vdots
   \end{cases}
$$

This can be written more concisely in terms of the [iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm) (log star).

Define $\log^*\!x$ as the number of times $\log$ needs to be applied to $x$ until it's less than 1 and $\log_k x$ to be $k$ iterations of $\log$, i.e.

$$ \log^*\!x =
  \begin{cases}
    0                  & x < 1 \\
    1 + \log^*(\log x) & x \geq 1
   \end{cases} \quad \text{and} \quad \log_k x = \underset{k}{\underbrace{\log \log \cdots \log }}\; x.$$

Then $f(x)$ can be written as

$$ f(x) = \prod_{k = 0}^{\log^*\!x-1} \frac{1}{\log_k x}. $$

By construction Ermakoff's test is inconclusive for $f(x)$, and the choices $\phi(x) = e^{e^x}$, $\phi(x) = e^{e^{e^x}}$, $\phi(x) = e^{e^{e^{e^x}}}$, $\ldots$ are all inconclusive too. One must take $\phi(x) = \text{tet}(x)$ ([tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration)), or anything that grows faster, to show this sum diverges.

Additionally, the integral test easily shows the divergence of the sum.

---

This approach can apply to any $\phi(x) > x$ where $\phi''(x) > 0$ and there is an $a > 0$ such that $\phi'(\phi^{-1}(a)) = 1$.

Let $\psi(x) = \phi^{-1}(x)$ and choose $a \geq 0$ such that $\phi'(\psi(a)) = 1$.

We can construct a continuous function satisfying

$$ f(\phi(x)) = f(x)/\phi'(x) \quad \text{and} \quad f(x) = 1 \;\; \text{for} \;\; 0 \leq x < a $$

through the same approach as above:

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      1 & 0 \leq x < a \\
      \frac{1}{\phi'(\psi(x))} & a \leq x < \phi(a) \\
      \frac{1}{\phi'(\psi(x))\phi'(\psi(\psi(x))} & \phi(a) \leq x < \phi(\phi(a)) \\
      \frac{1}{\phi'(\psi(x))\phi'(\psi(\psi(x))\phi'(\psi(\psi(\psi(x)))} & \phi(\phi(a)) \leq x < \phi(\phi(\phi(a))) \\
      \vdots & \vdots
   \end{cases}
$$